# Unwanted centering in lists

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

When I put a `center` environment at the beginning of an item in a list, the item itself becomes indented. How can I fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\emph{\large Enumerate}:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Foo.
\item
  \begin{center}
    Bar.
  \end{center}
\item Baz.
  \begin{center}
    Quux.
  \end{center}
\end{enumerate}

\emph{\large Itemize}:
\begin{itemize}
\item Foo.
\item
  \begin{center}
    Bar.
  \end{center}
\item Baz.
  \begin{center}
    Quux.
  \end{center}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you want to fix? Do you want to maintain a left-aligned numbering/bullet and the item in the middle?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\hfil` (see Bar under itemize)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\emph{\large Enumerate}:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Foo.
\item
  \begin{center}
    Bar.
  \end{center}
\item Baz.
  \begin{center}
    Quux.
  \end{center}
\end{enumerate}

\emph{\large Itemize}:
\begin{itemize}
\item Foo.
\item
{\hfil  Bar.}
\item Baz.
  \begin{center}
    Quux.
  \end{center}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I compiled your code in sharelatex and it still had the same weird indent and the bullet point for "Bar." under Enumerate was off to the left below "Foo." Maybe I missed something...?

Answer (score 2):

JPi's answer is good, but I thought I'd add an alternate solution - make it a table.

My code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{l c}
        \textit{Enumerate:} \\
       1. Foo.  &  2. Bar.\\
       \\
        3. Baz. & Quux. \\
        \\
        \textit{Itemize:} \\
        \textbullet Foo. & \textbullet Bar. \\
        \\
        \textbullet Baz. & Quux. \\
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which gives

[image]

I think this solution works just as well as using a list. If you wanted, you could change it from `{l c}` to `{l l}` and it'll look neater - the second column will be lined up but still in the middle.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you should definitely avoid the `table` floating environment.

Comment: never use `[h]` on its own it usually generates a warning fron latex that it is being changed to `ht` and any option without `p` increases the chance of the table going to the end of the document. (but as Johannes says, you don't want `table` here at all.)

Answer (score 2):

When you place the item in a box of width `\linewidth`, you can manage the alignment much more easily:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Original:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Foo.
  \item
    \begin{center}
      Bar.
    \end{center}
  \item Baz.
    \begin{center}
      Quux.
    \end{center}
\end{enumerate}

Updated:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Foo.
  \item \makebox[\linewidth]{Bar.}
  \item \makebox[0pt][l]{Baz.}%
      \makebox[\linewidth]{Quux.}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

By default `\makebox[<wd>]{<stuff>}` is equivalent to `\makebox[<wd>][c]{<stuff>}` that `c`entres `<stuff>` within a box of width `<wd>`.

Comment: You included a before picture...could you maybe include an after picture?

Comment: @heather: The picture includes an "Original" and an "Updated". The "Original" uses the OP's `center`, while the "Updated" uses `\makebox` constructions. `itemize` would work the same as `enumerate`, so I don't include it.

Comment: I see, sorry. The two seems to have teleported to the left...=)